# Unexpected 'Copyright' message in audio generated by Google Cloud Text to Speech API

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech

I am using the Google Cloud Text to Speech API with Python to generate audio files from text. However, I am encountering an issue where the generated audio contains an unexpected "Copyright" message in the middle of the audio. I have verified that I am using the official API and library, and that the input text does not contain the message. Additionally, I am within the $300 free trial credits limit

Comment: Are you using this [code](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio#text-to-speech-text-python) to generate audio files from text? Could you provide the input text and the output ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?